# Symfony : listener (or something else) to add salt in password when login_check

Tags: symfony, authentication, passwords, salt

When a user registers, I add a salt in the password :

```
$user->setPassword(
    $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
        $user,
        $newPassword.$user->getSalt()
    )
);
```

But now, how can I add this same salt in the user password when he logs in ?
FYI, I don't have a controller with loginAction ! My application is built with reactJs and Symfony Api. So, I just have a login_check.

Comment: The salt is stored in the user table and will be retrieved as part of the check_login process so it is not clear what you are asking.  How to generate a salt during registration?  Of course nowadays then is no need for an explicit salt so I assume you are working on a legacy application?  And catting the salt with a password makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks lxg for your answer :) It's not a legacy application. I think that I don't know how can I salt the password correctly. I have to add the salt in the user db and the salt will be retrieved automatically when the user logs in ?

Comment: First, go through the [security docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html).  Unless you are doing something very unusual you probably don't have to worry about the salt at all. Especially if you use what is known as the bycrypt password encorder.  It takes care of generating the salt for you and actually hashes it into the hashed password itself.  No developer salt required.  In any event, get the basic login stuff working first so you can see how all the pieces fit together.  Then customize if need be.

Comment: Oh ! Sorry !!! My question had no sense ! Now, I understand my mistake
Thanks to you :D

Answer (score 2):

The encoder has a `isPasswordValid` method:

```
$this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid(
    $user->getPassword(), // the user’s encrypted password in the DB
    $password,            // cleartext password as provided through UI or API
    $user->getSalt()      // the salt stored in the DB
);
```

Attention: This method does not throw an exception, but rather return a boolean. If it returns `false`, you must handle it appropriately, e.g. throw an exception yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is mine worked example Sf4 (I used on custom UserProvider and ApiPlatform)

```
class PasswordSubscriber implements EventSubscriber{
 /**
 * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
 */
private $encoder;

public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'prePersist' => 'encodePassword',
        'preUpdate'  => 'encodePassword',
    ];
}

/**
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
 */
public function encodePassword(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    if (!$entity instanceof User) {
        return;
    }
    if (!$entity->getPlainPassword()) {
        return;
    }
    $entity->setPassword($this->encoder->encodePassword($entity, $entity->getPlainPassword()));
}
```

}

P.S You no need to worry how encode password and check user
Just define firewall

```
 firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    docs:
        pattern:    ^/docs
        http_basic: ~
        provider: user_provider
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        provider: user_provider
        json_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            username_path: username
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

> And you can send post /login_check

```
{ "username":"username","password":"password"}
```

[How to Build a JSON Authentication Endpoint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html)